# .htaccess rewrite with dynamic script?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite, helicontech

i use the HeliconTech ModRewrite v3 on an Windows/IIS Webserver to make rewrites via an .htaccess File.

i have a db-Table with filename's to id's and want to a rewrite incoming urls with this constantly changing list.

Normaly, if using a map/list i use this code:

`#RewriteRule ^content/(.+)\.asp$ default.asp?ID=${map:$1} [L,NC]`

With makes *content/some_site.asp* to *default.asp?id=123*

Is it possible to fill the mapping file dynamic, e.g. via php or asp script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on IIS 7 then you can use [Helicon Ape](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/) instead. It is compatible with ISAPI_Rewrite 3 and it supports database maps.

[Introduction to database functionality of Helicon Ape](http://www.helicontech.com/articles/introduction-to-database-functionality-of-helicon-ape/)

[mod_dbd adticles](http://www.helicontech.com/articles/tag/mod_dbd/)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not -- ISAPI_Rewrite v3 does not support **prg:** type of mapping: see the [Apache mod_rewrite compatibility](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/compatibility.htm) page for exact details.